# Could not find member <method name> for struct type in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have the following code but when I try to chain using the following `x.initial(2).flatten()` I get a compile error saying `Could not find member flatten`

What am I doing wrong. To make sure I can keep chaining I am returning self after each chained method such as flatten, initial, etc.

```
struct $ {

    var resultArray: AnyObject[] = []
    init(array: AnyObject[]) {
        self.resultArray = array
    }

    mutating func first() -> AnyObject? {
        return $.first(self.resultArray)
    }

    mutating func flatten() -> $ {
        self.resultArray = $.flatten(self.resultArray)
        return self
    }

    static func first(array: AnyObject[]) -> AnyObject? {
        if array.isEmpty {
            return nil
        } else {
            return array[0]
        }
    }

    mutating func initial() -> $ {
        return self.initial(1)
    }

    mutating func initial(numElements: Int) -> $ {
        self.resultArray = $.initial(self.resultArray, numElements: numElements)
        return self
    }

    func value() -> AnyObject[] {
        return self.resultArray
    }

    static func flatten(array: AnyObject[]) -> AnyObject[] {
        var resultArr: AnyObject[] = []
        for elem : AnyObject in array {
            if let val = elem as? AnyObject[] {
                resultArr += self.flatten(val)
            } else {
                resultArr += elem
            }
        }
        return resultArr
    }

    static func initial(array: AnyObject[]) -> AnyObject[] {
        return self.initial(array, numElements: 1)
    }

    static func initial(array: AnyObject[], numElements: Int) -> AnyObject[] {
        var result: AnyObject[] = []
        for (index, _) in enumerate((0..array.count - numElements)) {
            result += array[index]
        }
        return result
    }

}

var x = $(array: [[1, 2], 3, [[4]]])
var y = x.initial(2).flatten() //Throws the error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `initial` returns an immutable instance of `$`. You are then trying to call a mutating method (`flatten`) on it. In order to mutate it again, you will have to store it in another variable that can be mutated. You could also change it to be a `class` instead of a `struct` because classes are mutable.

**Note** currently, the error message you are getting is terrible, but that is life with Swift at the moment.

Comment: Using class fixes the problem